# Apple USB keyboard - how to make function keys work as function keys (without having to use FN-key)

Tags: keyboard

I plugged in a regular Apple USB Keyboard, and it works nicely! Except.......

If I wish to press any Function keys, I need to hold down the Fn-Key and the function key to get it to talk to, SchismTracker, for instance.

What am I doing wrong, how do I make RPi simply recognize the keyboard as a regular keyboard without any craziness?

Bonus question - how do I map the "Fn"-key to be an Insert-key? :)

Answer (score 2):

A quick search returns [a blog entry](http://arcanesciencelab.wordpress.com/2014/02/02/tweaking-arch-on-the-pi/) which details how to make the function keys be the default. There is an option called fnmode in the Apple HID driver. You can test this by running:

```
echo 2 > /sys/module/hid_apple/parameters/fnmode
```

To make the change permanent, you need to edit `/etc/modprobe.d/hid_apple.conf` to have the following content:

```
options hid_apple fnmode=2
```